# Is there a free security log analyzer for apache?

Tags: security, apache-http-server, logging, analysis

What I need is a forensic log analyzer tool for apache to do the after math of a successful abuse of service attack which took place 2-3 month in the past. We are running a shared hosting service and one of our customers seems to have (or had) an exploitable script running. I suspect that I could find clues and hints in the logs but they are just too huge to browse through them manually or grep regexps from them.

Is there a tool which can do it and has predefined search patterns for known attacks and probably even heuristics to discover suspicious activities?

I do not look for a tool to do real-time blocking of such attempts because I need to analyze past logs and see if the exploit has been closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, [AWStats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/) can help you. It is a free and open-source tool.

**Edit/Update:**
Check out Phpida and Scalp as well. They are security analyzers looking for HTTP attacks, SQL injection etc.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpida/ 
http://code.google.com/p/apache-scalp/

Comment: AWStats is just a statistical analyzer and graphing tool, isn't it? Not much different from webalizer.

Comment: Yes, you're right. You can check Scalp and Phpida.

Comment: Scalp is probably the way to go and I will look into it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [WebForensik](http://sourceforge.net/projects/webforensik/)

It's a PHPIDS-based script (released under GPL2) to scan your HTTPD logfiles for attacks against web applications.

*Features:*

- supports standard log formats (common, combined)
- allows user-defined (mod_log_config syntax) formats
- automatically pipes your web logs through PHPIDS
- categorizes all incidents by type, impact, date, host...
- generates reports in CSV, HTML (sortable table), XML